# Vue.js Google Analytics and Tag Manager

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a Vue.js project that I wanna add analytics, but I am a bit confused between Tag Manager and Google Analytics.
I understand that GA cannot track anything, therefore we need the GTM to dispatch an event by using a trigger.

But my question is, if I am using vue-gtag and added the events into the code, such as buttons and other stuff and also enabled auto pageview tracking (I can see the reports on GA), do I need to set up everything on GTM?
What is a better practice, injecting the events into to code or defining everything in GTM (the code is compiled to an APK file if that matters)